# Filter Count on each SOQL Data Category Passed to Query

Tags: soql, filters, count, data-category

I have the following query that returns the **total** count:

```
SELECT Count()
FROM X__kav
WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online'
AND Language = 'en_US'
WITH DATA CATEGORY Foo_c AT (Bar_c, Baz__c)
```

How would I implement the query to return **two counts** one on each `Bar_c` and `Baz__c`?

Alternatively i could return run a query like this:

```
SELECT DATA_CATEGORY
FROM X__kav
WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online'
AND Language = 'en_US'
WITH DATA CATEGORY Foo_c AT (Bar_c, Baz__c)
```

Then in source code i could run a count on the two results, however I am unsure of what the correct term for selection of DATA_CATEGORY is.